# Using PySpark Pandas to read in filename with a space in it

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

trying to read this file:

```
abfss://myaccount@myorganisation.dfs.core.windows.net/perils_database/Bushfire AUSTRALIA - PERILS Industry Exposure Database 2023.xlsx
```

Using this Python code:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

input_file = "abfss://myaccount@myorganisation.dfs.core.windows.net/perils_database/Bushfire AUSTRALIA - PERILS Industry Exposure Database 2023.xlsx"

ps.read_excel(input_file)
```

I get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 97: abfss://myaccount@myorganisation.dfs.core.windows.net/perils_database/Bushfire AUSTRALIA - PERILS Industry Exposure Database 2023.xlsx
```

Because the file path has spaces in it. I'm unsure how to fix this using PySpark Pandas. Help?

Comment: Try to urlencode the `input_file`

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "cpfs-dbfs"

Comment: Try making it a raw string using the front `r` qualifier `input_file = r"abfss://myaccount@myorganisation.dfs.core.windows.net/perils_database/Bushfire AUSTRALIA - PERILS Industry Exposure Database 2023.xlsx"`